# Is my proof of if $A \subset B$ then $\sup A \le \sup B$ and $\sup (A\cup B) = \max(\sup A,\sup B)$, correct?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

for the first one :  if  $A \subset B$ then $\sup A \le \sup B$ :

Let $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ , we have $\forall a \in A$ : $a \in B$ and $\forall a \in A : $$\sup A \ge a$.

Suppose $\exists b_0 \in B$ such that $b_0 \ge \sup A$, then $b_0 \notin A$ becausee $\sup A \ge a$ for $\forall a \in A$, now we know that $\forall b \in B$, $\sup B \ge b$, then $\sup B \ge b_0 \ge \sup A$, then we get $\sup B \ge \sup A$, now if theres not that element $b_0 \in B$ such that $b_0 \ge \sup A$ and $b_0 \notin A$ , then $\sup A \ge b$ for $\forall b \in B$, then $\sup A \ge \sup B$ $(1)$, and since $a \in B$ then $\sup B \ge a$, so $\sup B \ge \sup A$ $(2)$, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $\sup A = \sup B$.

now for  $\sup (A\cup B) = \max(\sup A,\sup B)$:

Let $(A\cup B)$  = $\{ x ∣ x\in A \ $or$ \ x \in B \}$

we have $\sup A \ge x $ or $\sup B \ge x $ then $\max(\sup A,\sup B)\ge x$ then $$\tag1\max(\sup A,\sup B) \ge \sup (A\cup B)$$

now since $x$ can be $a$ or $b$, then $\sup (A\cup B) \ge x$ then :

$\sup (A\cup B) \ge a$. and :

$\sup (A\cup B) \ge b$.

then $$\tag2\sup (A\cup B) \ge \max(\sup A,\sup B)$$

from (1)  and (2) we deduce that $\max(\sup A,\sup B)$ = $\sup(A\cup B)$

I want to know what expressions/propositions am i not supposed to assume? and how can i fix them. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your proof is just fine. No mistakes and nothing assumed that you cant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let a∈A and b∈B , we have ∀a∈A : a∈B and ∀a∈A:supA≥a  Suppose ∃b0∈B... etc.

This is good and thorough and I have to give you credit for detail and care.

However this could be a lot more intuitive and simple: If $a \in A$ then $a \in B$ and (if $\sup B$ exists) , $\sup B \ge a$.  So $\sup B$ is an upper bound of $A$ as well as of $B$. [1]  So $\sup B \ge \sup A$.

Your answer to the second part is good and correct.

But consider this:

$A \subset A \cup B$ [2] so, by above, $\sup A\cup B \ge \sup A$.  Likewise $\sup A\cup B \ge \sup B$ so $\sup A\cup B \ge \max(\sup A, \sup B)$[3].

If $y \in A \cup B$ then either $y \in A$ and $y \le \sup A[4] \le \max(\sup A, \sup B)$ or $y \in B$ and $y \le \sup B \le \max(\sup A, \sup B)$.  Either way, $\max(\sup A, \sup B)$ is an upper bound of $A\cup B$ so $\sup A\cup B \le \max(\sup A, \sup B)$[5].

=======

[1]  You professor would probably like me to add:  If $s$ is an upper bound of $X$ then $s \ge \sup X$.  This follows directly from the the definition of *least* upper bound and is probably a proposition you have proven.

I did not include it, because I assumed it was a basic proposition that, once mentioned and proven, can be assumed to be self-evident.

Definition:  For a set $S$ that is bounded above, then if $s$ is such that i) $s$ is an upper bound of $S$ and ii) for any $y < s$ then $y$ is not an upper bound of $S$, the we say $s$ is the *least upper bound* of $S$ and we write it as $s = \sup S$.

(Trivial)Proposition:  If a set has a least upper bound, it is unique so $s = \sup S$ is well-defined to have a unique value (assuming such an $s$ exists at all).

Pf:  If $y < s$ then $y$ is not an upper bound by condition ii) for $s$, so $y$ is not a least upper bound as condition i) fails for $y$.  If $y > s$ the $s < y$ and as $s$ is an upper bound,  condition ii) fails for $y$.  So if $s$ is a least upper bound of $S$, it is the only upper bound of $S$.

Proposition: If $\sup S$ exists, then $x \ge \sup S \iff x$ is an upper bound of $S$.

Pf: If $x \ge \sup S$, then if $a\in S$ then $a\le \sup S$ as $\sup S$ is an upper bound.  If $x \ge \sup S$ and $\sup S \ge a$ then $a \le x$ so $x$ is an upper bound of $S$.

If $x$ is an upper bound of $S$ then it is impossible bur $x < \sup S$ (as that would violate condition ii)) so $x \ge \sup S$.

[2] I really hope your professor would accept that $A \subset A\cup B$ without explanation.

If not... for all $a \in A$ then $a \in A$ or $a \in B$ so $a \in A\cup B$.

[3] ditto, I assume $a \ge x$ and $a \ge y$ means $a\ge \max(x,y)$ should be self-evident.

[4] by definition, $\sup A$ is an upper bound so $\sup A \ge y$ for all $y\in A$.

[5] see footnote 1:

Comment: thank you, I don't know but my analysis teacher kept telling us to write out everything that is supposed to be written be it simple or not so i took the advice too literally i guess, i'm kind of new to proof writing so i just want to write long proofs even if they're not needed just to get used to the writing, thanks again.

Comment: Your professor is probably correct.  In which case I probably should have added extra comments.  I'll put them in as footnotes.

Comment: I added 5) footnotes that your professor may wish to have explicitly stated (1,4,5 especially).  I, personally, think that once one learns the definition we can assume these as self-evident.  But I suppose one should be able to justify these if asked.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the ideas of both proofs are good, the formalism is not, and there are mistakes even if we understand the good idea behind them. So technically no, it's not correct. And for both proofs (especially the first one) you can do it simpler, especially the first part.

The biggest problem is that you lack some $\forall$ and "Let $a \in A$" statements in both parts, especially the second one.

The first part is messy and more complicated than it needs, and has little flaws. The statement $b_0 \notin A$ is false (since you've been using $\geq$ sign and $\sup A$ may be in $A$), but luckily useless, so you should remove it. You should break the proof into more sentences to make it more readable. The statement "since $a \in B$ then $\sup B \ge a$" has no meaning, since $a$ is not defined here, you should write something like since $\forall a \in A, a \in B$ so $\forall a \in A, \sup B \ge a$ .

For the second part, you absolutely need to set x, a, b when you use them, with "Let $x \in A \cup B$" or "$\forall x \in A \cup B$" statements for instance. Without them x, a, b are never defined, the proof is not good at all although we understand (because the teacher knows you should be using $\forall$ for instance, but technically he could interpret "no definition" as $\exists$, and you have no proof anymore). To prove (2) you're also going a bit too fast I think, you should not skip the $\sup(A \cup B) \geq \sup A$ statement (and the same for $B$).

You can do way simpler:

1. $\forall a \in A, a\in B$ so $\forall a \in A, a \leq \sup B$, so $\sup A \leq \sup B$.
2. $A, B \subseteq A \cup B$ so the first part gives (2). Get (1) as you're doing.

Comment: yeah for the second proof i kind of went lazy and just skipped most of what i was supposed to write.
i felt that my first proof is unnecessarily complicated but i just wrote the first idea i had in my mind, thanks for the critics, will try to improve them next time i guess.